# Lithium framework multiple 'or' statements in a query (using mongoDB)

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I have started work with lithium framework + mongoDB recently. I want to do a really simple query which contains multiple or statements.
I have articles in the DB with publish_up and publish_down fields. I want to fetch only those records/documents which pulbis_down field is highert than now OR null AND publish_up field lower than now OR null.

```
$items = $article::find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '$or' => array(
            '$gt' => array('publish_down', $mongoDateNow),
            'publish_down' => $mongDateNull
        ),
        '$or' => array(
            '$lt' => array('publish_up', $mongoDateNow),
            'publish_up' => $mongDateNull
        ),
    )
));
```

Of course this snippet is wrong hence the second or statement overwrites the first one (because the same array key).
I tried to wrap them into an individual array but gives error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

This query will fetch articles with (publish_down > now **OR** publish_down = null) **AND** (publish_up < now **OR** publish_up = null)

```
    $items = Articles::find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            '$or' => array(
                array('publish_down' => array('$gt' => $mongoDateNow)),
                array('publish_down' => null)
            ),
            '$or' => array(
                array('publish_up' => array('$lt' => $mongoDateNow)),
                array('publish_up' => null)
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about lithium but in PHP you can use multiple $OR as below

```
$items = $article::find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '$or' => array(
        array(
            '$gt' => array('publish_down', $mongoDateNow),
            'publish_down' => $mongDateNull
        ),
        array(
            '$lt' => array('publish_up', $mongoDateNow),
            'publish_up' => $mongDateNull
        )
        ),
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is:

```
'$and' => array(
    array(
        '$or'=>array(
            array('publish_up' => null),
            array('publish_up' => array('$lt' => $mongoDateNow))
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$or'=>array(
            array('publish_down' => null), 
            array('publish_down' => array('$gt' => $mongoDateNow))
        )
    )
)
```